# Can't get program to print "not in sentence" when word not in sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, words, enumerate, sentence

I have a program that asks for input of a sentence, then asks for a word, and tells you the position of that word:

```
sentence = input("enter sentence: ").lower()
askedword = input("enter word to locate position: ").lower()
words = sentence.split(" ")

for i, word in enumerate(words):
     if askedword == word :
          print(i+1)
    #elif keyword != words :
         #print ("this not")
```

However I cannot get the program to work correctly when I edit it to say that if the input word is not in the sentence, then print "this isn't in the sentence"

Answer (score 5):

Lists are sequences, as such you can use [the `in` operation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) on them to test for membership in the `words` list. If inside, find the position inside the sentence with `words.index`:

```
sentence = input("enter sentence: ").lower()
askedword = input("enter word to locate position: ").lower()
words = sentence.split(" ")

if askedword in words:
    print('Position of word: ', words.index(askedword))
else:
    print("Word is not in the given sentence.")
```

With sample input:

```
enter sentence: hello world

enter word to locate position: world
Position of word: 1
```

and, a false case:

```
enter sentence: hello world

enter word to locate position: worldz
Word is not in the given sentence.
```

If you're looking to check against multiple matches then a list-comprehension with `enumerate` is the way to go:

```
r = [i for i, j in enumerate(words, start=1) if j == askedword]
```

Then check on whether the list is empty or not and print accordingly:

```
if r:
    print("Positions of word:", *r)
else:
    print("Word is not in the given sentence.")
```

Comment: this only locates the first time the word is there in the sentence, for example if i input sentence dog sat on the dog, its should come up with 1 and 5, is there anyway i can do this ?

Comment: @Dummy8123 right, none of the answers apparently caught on you wanted to check for multiple occurrences, I updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 3):

Jim's answer—combining a test for `askedword in words` with a call to `words.index(askedword)`—is the best and most Pythonic approach in my opinion.

Another variation on the same approach is to use `try`-`except`:

```
try:
    print(words.index(askedword) + 1) 
except ValueError:
    print("word not in sentence")
```

However, I just thought I'd point out that the structure of the OP code looks like you might have been attempting to adopt the following pattern, which also works:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if askedword == word :
        print(i+1)
        break
else:    # triggered if the loop runs out without breaking
    print ("word not in sentence")
```

In an unusual twist unavailable in most other programming languages, this `else` binds to the `for` loop, not to the `if` statement (that's right, get your editing hands off my indents). [See the python.org documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: i have tried the try and except one however it only seems to be outputted the first locatioin